# Advice on setting up model in a MVVM application using caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm new to MVVM so I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to do this. I'm using WPF with Caliburn Micro for this.

I have two different views (each with their view models) for the model I'm trying to manipulate. One view shows the model in a tree view while the other shows a table view of the data.

My model basically looks something like the following

```
 public class Foo
 {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string[] Categories {get;set;}
 }
```

The Views are different ways to visualize collections of Foo. The table view is pretty straightforward, but the tree-view will group Foo by the category it contains.

So if an instance of Foo is something like

var fo = new Foo(){Name="one",Categories=new[]{"a","b","c"}};

Then the treeview would be

a

|_ one

b

|_ one

c

|_ one

I have two questions about how to connect the model to the view model in the spirit of MVVM.

1. What is the best way to populate the viewmodels from the model for the different views? I was thinking something like a singleton `FooManager` that is accessed from the view models. Or would using the caliburns `SimpleContainer` be better suited for this?
2. Lets say I manipulate Foo in the table view by changing it's category collection. How would I propagate the change to the treeview, since that would mean that Foo would appear in a different tree node? Would Foo need to implement `PropertyChangedBase' and somehow bubble up the changes to the other ViewModel? Or would it be better for`FooManager`to implement`PropertyChangedBase`. Seems like the latter would be more reasonable.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For collections that change reference BindableCollection and are presented on the view.

As for bringing data into a view you can do it through a combination of DI/IoC, via constructor injections on the ViewModel in question.  Most of that is done thru Interfaces that can be found in the Container of your choosing either SimpleContainer to MEF if you prefer or what ever IOC/DI container you choose really, the framework is such that can be extended with any container.  Going with Interfaces allows for mocking and unit testing of the viewmodels.

Yes bubbling of the change to the View is usually done through what you had though by means of implementing INotifyPropertyChange which is part of the PropertyChangedBase class object.

One thing that will probably rear its ugly head is that Collections based off ObservableCollection don't necessarily bubble the changes of the underlying item's properties in the collection, that is an entirely different thread on SO

Comment: I ended up avoid IoC for now since by model data provider will not change most likely and have the additional dependency is not a big deal. I also made multiple views for a single ViewModel so I dont need to worry about trying to sync multiple view models with the model data.